# How to insert a vertex with link type property with the orientjs query builder?

Tags: orientdb, oriento

I am trying to insert a vertex with orientjs(previously oriento) query builder. My class has a link type property pointing to another class.

I know I can get it to work with a raw query string but I would love to use the query builder.

Here is what I've tried so far :

```
db.insert()
.into('VertexClassName')
.set({"prop":"value", "linkProperty":"33:1289287"})

db.insert()
.into('VertexClassName')
.set({"prop":"value", "linkProperty":"#33:1289287"})
```

I get the following error :

```
Error on saving record in cluster #13
```

Am I setting properties in the right way ?
Could the error be related to somtehing else ? 
I have sucessfully ran an insert query in the cluster #13 with a raw query string in the studio...

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation it seems that the problem might be at the end of your statement

```
db.insert().into('VertexClassName')
    .set({"prop":"value", "linkProperty":"33:1289287"}).one()
    .then(function (data) {
       // callback
});
```

Check if your code works adding one() to the pipe line

**EDITED**: I found this method in orientjs.

```
db.create('VERTEX', 'V')
.set({
  key: 'value',
  foo: 'bar'
})
.one()
.then(function (vertex) {
  console.log('created vertex', vertex);
});
```

When using Tinkerpop API they recommend using createVertex instead of insert, because createVertex is intended for graphs and insert for Documents... Could you try with the create() method instead?

Comment: Doesn't change anything

Comment: Could you provide more info, like server creation config?, are you using credentials? Does it work if you execute an insert query insted of using the insert() method?

Answer (score 0):

I am using SQL and it worked.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Station set linked = (select from LinkedClass where LinkedProb = 'value'), prop = 'value'"

OrientVertex vertex = new OrientVertex();
vertex = graph.command(new OCommandSQL(sql)).execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible unless you've added a proper field with the right type 'Link' in your schema. (which I rarely do).

Now instead of having the right 'link' type inserted you can do the opposite, store is as a String, and leverage the query functions to use it correctly:

```
db.insert().into('table').set({prop: '#15:14'}).one();
```

And it will be converted as String (which is a bit sad) but then you can use that in your queries:

```
SELECT eval(prop) FROM table;
```

And it will be 'eval'-ed to a Node RecordID that you can directly use and call functions like expand() on.

For example:

```
SELECT name FROM (SELECT expand(eval(prop)) FROM table);
```

Will eval the node stored in the insert(), grab the node, expand it and collect its name property.

Comment: If you have a field in the schema however, you can probably do: db.insert().into('table').set({prop: db.rawExpression('eval("#15:14")')});